# Ver historico de numeros colocados no input

Tags: javascript, histórico

Olá
Eu estou fazendo um projeto de site de apostas de números de 1 a 100 e preciso que o usuário consiga ver os números e valores apostados, tipo um histórico. Para esse projeto estou utilizando HTML, CSS e JS.
Toda ajuda é bem vinda.

Vou deixar o trecho do código que estou usando para validar as apostas do usuário.

```html
<body>
    <h1>Descubra o número de 1 a 100</h1>
    <h3 id="saldo">Saldo: 100€</h3>
    
    <label for="">Escolha um número</label>
    <input type="number" id="bet" placeholder="Entre 1 a 100"> <br> 
    
    <label for="">Faça sua aposta:</label>
    <input type="number" id="valorbet" placeholder="Superior a 0€"><br>

    <button onclick="verifyNumber()">Sortear</button>

    <button onclick="historico()">Historico</button>


    <script src="script.js"></script>   
</body>
```

```js
var numberToFind = 0;
var attempts = 0;
var saldo = 100;

function refresh(){

    var element = document.getElementById('bet');
    element.value = '';
    var element2 = document.getElementById('valorbet');
    element2.value = '';
    
    numberToFind = parseInt(Math.random() * 101);
    attempts = 0;

    console.log('The number to find: '+numberToFind);
}

refresh();


function verifyNumber(){
    var element = document.getElementById('bet');
    var bet = element.value;
    var valorbet = document.getElementById('valorbet');
    var vbet = Number(valorbet.value);

    let n = [];

    if(bet < 1){
        alert("GAME OVER!")
        window.location.reload(true);   
        return;
    }

    if(saldo == 0){
        alert("FIM DE JOGO! Seu saldo é 0€. Você teve "+attempts+ " erros");
        window.location.reload(true);
        return;
    }

    if(vbet > saldo || vbet == 0){
        alert("Faça uma aposta superior a 0€ ou o saldo é insuficiente!");
        return;
    }
    if(bet > 100)
    {
        alert('Aposta é inválida');
        return;
    }

    if(bet > numberToFind)
    {
        attempts++;
        alert(' O número para ser encontrado é MENOR');
        document.body.style.background = "rgb(205, 46, 46)";
        saldo-=vbet;
        document.getElementById("saldo").innerHTML = `Saldo é ${saldo}€`;
        n.push(bet);
    }
    else if(bet < numberToFind)
    {
        
        attempts++;
        alert(' O número para ser encontrado é MAIOR')
        document.body.style.background = "rgb(205, 46, 46)";
        saldo-=vbet;
        document.getElementById("saldo").innerHTML = `Saldo é ${saldo}€`;
        

    }
    else
    {
        document.body.style.background = "rgb(32, 201, 32)";
        alert('✅ Parabéns você acertou!! Com '+attempts+' erros.Seus numeros'+ n);
        saldo+=vbet;
        document.getElementById("saldo").innerHTML = `Saldo é ${saldo}€`;
        refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Em vez de ter `attempts` como um número de tentativas, iniciando em 0, inicie como uma array vazia e vá adicionando a essa array as tentativas erradas. Quando precisar saber o número de tentativas realizadas, é `attempts.length`. O histórico pode até ficar sempre à mostra numa div: na `verifyNumber()`, depois de inserir a tentativa nova em `attempts`, você transforma a array em string com `attempts.join()` e coloca essa string na div do histórico.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Certo como você só colocou o HTML do botão do histórico suponho que você queira a resposta da lógica toda, se não falta informação, outro detalhe e que oriento que utilize os recursos do stackoverflow que tem essa opção de inserir HTML e JavaScript, se encontra na parte superior tem um ícone <>.
Mas vamos lá eu faria o seguinte:

```js
var numberToFind = 0;
var attempts = 0;
var saldo = 100;

function refresh(){

    var element = document.getElementById('bet');
    element.value = '';
    var element2 = document.getElementById('valorbet');
    element2.value = '';
    
    numberToFind = parseInt(Math.random() * 101);
    attempts = 0;

    console.log('The number to find: '+numberToFind);
}

refresh();

var arrHistoricoSaldo =[]; // criei um array com o saldo inicial
var arrHistoricoNumeroApostado = []; // criei um array com os numeros iniciais de 1 a 100

function verifyNumber(){
    var element = document.getElementById('bet');
    var bet = element.value;
    var valorbet = document.getElementById('valorbet');
    var vbet = valorbet.value;
    
    arrHistoricoSaldo.push(bet);
    arrHistoricoNumeroApostado.push(vbet)
    // aqui toda vez que o usuario clica em sortear os numeros inseridos vao para dentro ddos respectivos arrays.
    
    
    

    let n = [];

    if(bet < 1){
        alert("GAME OVER!")
        window.location.reload(true);   
        return;
    }

    if(saldo == 0){
        alert("FIM DE JOGO! Seu saldo é 0€. Você teve "+attempts+ " erros");
        window.location.reload(true);
        return;
    }

    if(vbet > saldo || vbet == 0){
        alert("Faça uma aposta superior a 0€ ou o saldo é insuficiente!");
        return;
    }
    if(bet > 100)
    {
        alert('Aposta é inválida');
        return;
    }

    if(bet > numberToFind)
    {
        attempts++;
        alert(' O número para ser encontrado é MENOR');
        document.body.style.background = "rgb(205, 46, 46)";
        saldo-=vbet;
        document.getElementById("saldo").innerHTML = `Saldo é ${saldo}€`;
        n.push(bet);
    }
    else if(bet < numberToFind)
    {
        
        attempts++;
        alert(' O número para ser encontrado é MAIOR')
        document.body.style.background = "rgb(205, 46, 46)";
        saldo-=vbet;
        document.getElementById("saldo").innerHTML = `Saldo é ${saldo}€`;
        

    }
    else
    {
        document.body.style.background = "rgb(32, 201, 32)";
        alert('✅ Parabéns você acertou!! Com '+attempts+' erros.Seus numeros'+ n);
        saldo+=vbet;
        document.getElementById("saldo").innerHTML = `Saldo é ${saldo}€`;
        refresh();
    }
}
n = 0
var element = document.getElementById('historic');
function historico() {
   
    document.getElementById("historicN").innerHTML = ` Numeros apostados: ${arrHistoricoNumeroApostado} : `
    document.getElementById("historicV").innerHTML = ` Valores apostados: ${arrHistoricoSaldo} `

}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Descubra o número de 1 a 100</h1>
    <h3 id="saldo">Saldo: 100€</h3>
    
    <label for="">Escolha um número</label>
    <input type="number" id="bet" placeholder="Entre 1 a 100"> <br> 
    
    <label for="">Faça sua aposta:</label>
    <input type="number" id="valorbet" placeholder="Superior a 0€"><br>

    <button onclick="verifyNumber()">Sortear</button>
    <button onclick="historico()">Historico</button>
    <p id="historicN">Numeros</p>
    <br>
    <p id="historicV">Valores</p>
    

    <script src="script.js"></script>   
</body>
```

Bom basicamente inseri dois arrays, e quando voce clica pra apostar, adiciona nesses arrays o que os valores do imput, depois basicamente imprimo o array

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Hairy Skull. Deu certo.